# Doctrine_Connection_Exception' with message 'PDO Connection Error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045]

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, doctrine, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-2

Please help me get to the bottom of this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Connection_Exception' with message 'PDO Connection Error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

Checked my Database config file and it reads correctly,

Below is my config file:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'mypassword';
$db['default']['database'] = 'mydb';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

If it will be of any help I'm running Doctrine 2.xx + COdeigniter 2.xx

Comment: @Zombiehunter I need to know how to make it pick the password I have specified in the database config file

Comment: @user587244 show us your config file (and change your password)

Comment: Hey @j0k, thanks, edited the question to include the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Removing password in phpmyAdmin seems to solve problem, albeit temporarily.

Interestingly ,editing the codeigniter

> config.php

does not seem to affect Connection status/ Error for that matter.

Make sure to allow phpmyAdmin login without Password through COmmenting out

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;

in

> /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

Thanks.

Comment: But you never talk about phpMyAdmin is your question ... I don't understand why modify a config in phpMyAdmin will fix your problem with codeigniter & doctrine in your application ... o_O

Comment: @j0k I agree it doesn't solve the problem , just avoids it. When I use a password, problem recurs.Downvote!